# is it safe to use EmptyWorkingSet like this?

Tags: c, autohotkey, keylogger

I've been working on an app that sends keystrokes to mimic user actions. For this, I want to record my keystrokes. I looked around on the internet on how to go about such a task, and I found a program called Key Catcher. Because I'm worried of getting a malicious keylogger on my device I'm reading the source code first, and I found this line:

```
   return, dllcall("psapi.dll\EmptyWorkingSet", "UInt", -1)
```

I didn't know what this command was and a google search gave internet forums warning not to use EmptWorkingSet yourself, but also examples of specific programs using this without problems. Could anyone explain how this should be used? or if this will give problems? or could someone give a better alternative?

PS: this command is used everytime a process finishes if that helps

Comment: If you want a good answer, you need at least a good meaningful title for your question.

Answer (score 1):

The "EmptyWorkingSet" operation removes as many of the application's pages as possible from memory. It is often used mistakenly by people who think that having lots of free RAM is good.

It generally won't do very much harm. The pages can be loaded back into RAM fairly quickly if needed. But the only good it does is make the amount of free memory pages go up, which is actually slightly harmful.

It's basically neither here nor there. It's very bad to call it from a process that's performance critical because it will slow the process down. It's possibly useful to call it from a process that has accumulated a lot of cruft in RAM that doesn't need to be there. But the OS will already remove that stuff from RAM itself.

Comment: thanks for your response! What do you mean with: But the only good it does is make the amount of free memory pages go up, which is actually slightly harmful. How would that be harmful?

Comment: @mxyzptlk It takes effort to make the pages free. And for there to be any benefit to having free pages, the OS has to make them used again. So it's two steps that essentially cancel each other out. The OS can change pages from one use to another, so making them free when the OS could already make them free if it wanted to only takes options away from the OS.